# magento xml import mapping

Tags: php, xml, magento

I would like to map xml categories to my magento categories.

I put together import script which works, but it does not import into any categories in magento.

In script im testting I would like to import product that has in xml

```
<izdelekKategorija>Komponente</izdelekKategorija>
```

into magento category number 738.

Im asking for some help Im a beginner in PHP.

Thank you.

```
    <?php
$kat = array(
'Komponente' => '738',
);


class TestLogger
{

    /**
     * logging methos
     *
     * @param string $data
     *            : log content
     * @param string $type
     *            : log type
     */
    public function log($data, $type)
    {
        echo "$type:$data\n";
    }
}

// setup include PATH's
set_include_path('magmi' . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'magmi/inc' . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'magmi/integration/inc' . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'magmi/engines'); 

// end include PATH's

require_once("magmi_datapump.php");    // call Datapump

$dp=Magmi_DataPumpFactory::getDataPumpInstance("productimport");
$dp->beginImportSession("123", "create", new TestLogger());        // default- name of profile ,  create - we want to create and update items



 $file="test.xml";

$microline = new SimpleXMLElement($file, null, true);            // load XML

$izdelek = array ((string)$item->izdelekKategorija);

global $kat;
$izdelek = array ((string)$item->izdelekKategorija);
$kategorija = (isset($kat[$izdelek]) ? $kat[$izdelek] : $kategorija);

foreach ($microline as $item){



    $newProductData = array(
            "sku"           => (string)$item->izdelekID .=' inbbt',
            "name"          => (string)$item->izdelekIme,        // name
            "attribute_set" => "test",            // attribute_set
            "store"         => "test",  
            "category_ids"  => $kategorija,
            "tax_class_id"  => "3",         
    );


   $dp->ingest($newProductData);
   echo '' . ' mem:'.memory_get_usage() .  " ... Done! <br />\n";            //memory usage check
    $newProductData=null;    //clear memory
    unset($newProductData); //clear memory
}
unset($microline);

$dp->endImportSession();   // end import
?>
```

Edit: I managed to get script working and it's importing ok, but it does not import images from url...

New working code:

```
    <?php

$spisekKategorij = array(
'Komponente' => '738',
'Prenosniki' => '742',
'Monitorji' => '737',
);

class TestLogger
{

    /**
     * logging methos
     *
     * @param string $data
     *            : log content
     * @param string $type
     *            : log type
     */
    public function log($data, $type)
    {
        echo "$type:$data\n";
    }
}

// setup include PATH's
set_include_path('magmi' . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'magmi/inc' . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'magmi/integration/inc' . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'magmi/engines'); 

// end include PATH's

require_once("magmi_datapump.php");    // call Datapump

$dp=Magmi_DataPumpFactory::getDataPumpInstance("productimport");
$dp->beginImportSession("123", "create");        // default- name of profile ,  create - we want to create and update items

$file="test.xml";

$microline = new SimpleXMLElement($file, null, true);            // load XML


// $kategorija = $izdelek;
 // $kategorija = (isset($spisekKategorij[$izdelek]) ? $spisekKategorij[$izdelek] : $kategorija);


foreach ($microline as $item){
$izdelek = ((string)$item->izdelekKategorija);
 $kategorija = (($spisekKategorij[$izdelek]) ? $spisekKategorij[$izdelek] : $kategorija);


    $newProductData = array(
            "sku"           => (string)$item->izdelekID .=' abbt',
            "name"          => (string)$item->izdelekIme,        
            'price'         => ((real)$item->cenaBrezddv),
            'description'   => (string)$item->izdelekOpis . (string)$item->izdelekDodatenOpis,
            'short_description' => (string)$item->izdelekDodatenOpis,
            'diagonala_rshop' => (string)$item->velikost_zaslona,
            'procesor_rshop' => (string)$item->procesor,
            'ram_rshop' => (string)$item->ram,
            'hdd_rshop' => (string)$item->disk,
            'operacijski_rshop' => (string)$item->licencna_nalepka,
            'locljivost_rshop' => (string)$item->locljivost,
            'grafika_rshop' => (string)$item->grafika,
            "attribute_set" => "test",            
            "store"         => "rshop",  
            "category_ids"  => $kategorija,
            );


$newProductData["image"]='+'.(string)$item->slike->slika1;        // + show picture, - dont show picture
$newProductData['small_image']='+'.(string)$item->slike->slika1;            // small img
$newProductData['thumbnail']='+'.(string)$item->slike->slika1;

echo $izdelek;
echo $kategorija;
echo $slika;

echo '<pre>'; print_r($newProductData); echo '</pre>';



$dp->ingest($newProductData);


  echo '' . ' mem:'.memory_get_usage() .  " ... Done! <br />\n";            //memory usage check
    $newProductData=null;    //clear memory
    unset($newProductData); //clear memory
}
unset($microline);

$dp->endImportSession();   // end import
?>
```

Comment: You perhaps should, as you managed to answer the question about the category, not update your question but instead formulate an answer that explains what the solution was and why. Then you can ask a new question because the question you have now is different (you can link in your new question to your previous one to give it some context). This is important for a Q&A site as we collect questions *and* answers for *future* visitors, so that others can benefit from your question and answers as from mine.

Answer (score 0):

Solution to my question is to move

```
$izdelek = ((string)$item->izdelekKategorija);
 $kategorija = (($spisekKategorij[$izdelek]) ? $spisekKategorij[$izdelek] : $kategorija);
```

into foreach loop.

Comment: Please also write why the previous code in the question didn't work, so the reasoning to move the code becomes clear. That's better as just dropping the code. Thanks for taking the comment into account, don't forget to edit the question as well and shorten the text in there (the part after edit: seems redundant now with the new question in place).