# Magento xml importing - pictures are not imported

Tags: php, xml, magento

I managed to get script for importing products with mapping of fields from XML working.([magento xml import mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32028606/magento-xml-import-mapping)).

I use Magmi importer, here is link to magmi image attributes processor plugin which is (as I discovered later) mandatory to import pictures from URL: http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=Image_attributes_processor

But can't get to import pictures (link to the picture is in XML as URL).

One product from XML:

```xml
<izdelek>
    <st>1</st>
    <izdelekID>75</izdelekID>
    <izdelekIme>ATI Radeon 102 - B62902 (B)</izdelekIme>
    <izdelekPodnaslov>256 MB, DMS - 59</izdelekPodnaslov>
    <izdelekOpis></izdelekOpis>
    <izdelekKategorija>Komponente</izdelekKategorija>
    <izdelekDodatenOpis>
        Grafična kartica omogoča razširjeno namizje na dveh ekranih (dve različni sliki)! LOW PROFILE - namenjena
        izključno SFF računalnikom!
    </izdelekDodatenOpis>
    <zadnja_osvezitev>16/08/2015</zadnja_osvezitev>
    <url>http://www.bbt.si/ati-radeon-102-b62902-b</url>
    <garancija>6 mesecev</garancija>
    <opis>PCIe</opis>
    <slike>
        <slika1>
            http://www.bbt.si/modules/uploader/uploads/s_product/pictures/crop1/graficna-kartica-ati-102-b62902.jpg
        </slika1>
    </slike>
    <cena>12.20</cena>
    <cenaBrezddv>10.00</cenaBrezddv>
    <zaloga>več na zalogi</zaloga>
</izdelek>
```

Need some advice what is wrong with this code:

```
<?php

$spisekKategorij = array(
    'Komponente' => '738',
    'Prenosniki' => '742',
    'Monitorji'  => '737',
);

class TestLogger
{
    /**
     * logging methos
     *
     * @param string $data
     *            : log content
     * @param string $type
     *            : log type
     */
    public function log($data, $type)
    {
        echo "$type:$data\n";
    }
}

// setup include PATH's
set_include_path('magmi' . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'magmi/inc' . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'magmi/integration/inc' . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'magmi/engines');

// end include PATH's

require_once("magmi_datapump.php");    // call Datapump

$dp = Magmi_DataPumpFactory::getDataPumpInstance("productimport");
$dp->beginImportSession("123", "create"); // "default" - name of profile ,  "create" - we want to create and update items

$file = "test.xml";

$microline = new SimpleXMLElement($file, null, true); // load XML

foreach ($microline as $item) {
    $izdelek    = ((string) $item->izdelekKategorija);
    $kategorija = (($spisekKategorij[$izdelek]) ? $spisekKategorij[$izdelek] : $kategorija);


    $newProductData = array(
        "sku"               => (string) $item->izdelekID .= ' abbt',
        "name"              => (string) $item->izdelekIme,
        'price'             => ((real) $item->cenaBrezddv),
        'description'       => (string) $item->izdelekOpis . (string) $item->izdelekDodatenOpis,
        'short_description' => (string) $item->izdelekDodatenOpis,
        'diagonala_rshop'   => (string) $item->velikost_zaslona,
        'procesor_rshop'    => (string) $item->procesor,
        'ram_rshop'         => (string) $item->ram,
        'hdd_rshop'         => (string) $item->disk,
        'operacijski_rshop' => (string) $item->licencna_nalepka,
        'locljivost_rshop'  => (string) $item->locljivost,
        'grafika_rshop'     => (string) $item->grafika,
        "attribute_set"     => "test",
        "store"             => "rshop",
        "category_ids"      => $kategorija,
    );


    $newProductData["image"]       = '+' . (string) $item->slike->slika1; // + show picture, - dont show picture
    $newProductData['small_image'] = '+' . (string) $item->slike->slika1; // small img
    $newProductData['thumbnail']   = '+' . (string) $item->slike->slika1;

    echo $izdelek;
    echo $kategorija;
    echo $slika;

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($newProductData);
    echo '</pre>';


    $dp->ingest($newProductData);


    echo '' . ' mem:' . memory_get_usage() . " ... Done! <br />\n";  //memory usage check
}

unset($microline);

$dp->endImportSession(); // end import
```

Comment: Your question would become more clear when you provide some XML as example.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me. I added xml.

Comment: If you're using the magmi importer you should make this visible in your question. You should also reference the importers documentation on how to import images and show where you did this and with which specific action you've got a problem so your question is more clear (the more clear your question is, the more near and useful an answer can be).

Answer (score 0):

I was too quick to ask question ... problem was with magmi configuration so solution is:

- enable Magmi Image attributes processor plugin
- use "default" profile with

  $dp->beginImportSession("123", "create");

(123 was wrong magmi profile) so right line must be:

```
$dp->beginImportSession("default", "create");
```